# Scala - using parametrized type inside parametrized type

Tags: java, scala

I am trying to compile following code:

```
case class Settings(settingsList:List[Setting])
abstract class Setting[T](name:String, value:T)
```

but the compiler complains:

```
Error:(9, 54) class Setting takes type parameters
case class Settings(settingsList:List[Setting])
                                                     ^
```

but the equivalent Java code compiles sucesfully:

```
public class Settings {
    List<Setting> settingsList;
}

abstract class Setting<T> {
    abstract T getValue();
    abstract String getName();
}
```

What's so different about scala that it would not allow such behaviour?

Answer (score 3):

You just need a wildcard type:

```
case class Settings(settingsList:List[Setting[_]])
abstract class Setting[T](name:String, value:T)
```

This is equivalent to your Java code.

Answer (score 1):

Java has been generified with version 5, and AFAIK for backwards compatibility you can omit the type parameters. Also Java has use-site variance which usually makes these things very annoying to type, as opposed to use-site variance in Scala. Without change you could use an existential type `List[Setting[_]]` in Scala, but probably better is to use the right variance:

```
case class Settings(settingsList: List[Setting[Any]])

abstract class Setting[+A](name: String, value: A)
```

Comment: Messing with variance is not necessarily the best idea. Depending on implementation details for Setting, covariance may not make sense, and will limit design. A wildcard is seems like the way to go.

Comment: @UlysseMizrahi It's not "messing". I recommend to always annotate types with variance where it makes sense. That's the way a sub-typing based system works, and Scala prefers immutable data structures so this makes a lot of sense. Where this is not possible, as I have noted, you can use an existential (wildcard) type.

Comment: "That's the way a sub-typing based system works" - this is simply not true, and although covariance is indeed related to immutability, forcing covariance means being unable to use the type in method parameters (which may be desirable even in immutable structures). Furthermore, variance has an actual meaning in terms of type design. Do we want a Setting[List[Int]] to be a Setting[Iterable[Int]] ? It may not make sense from a design point of view.

Comment: ""That's the way a sub-typing based system works" - this is simply not true". Ahem. Yes, it's true. It's wrong to avoid thinking about variance in Scala. It's almost always useful to properly annotate your types. It helps design and inference.

Answer (score 0):

> the equivalent Java code compiles sucesfully

`Setting` without a type parameter is a raw type. According to [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8),

> > The use of raw types is allowed only as a concession to compatibility of legacy code. The use of raw types in code written after the introduction of genericity into the Java programming language is strongly discouraged. It is possible that future versions of the Java programming language will disallow the use of raw types.

The correct way to write this in Java is

```
List<Setting<?>> settingsList;
```

and the Scala equivalent is `List[Setting[_]]`, as the other answers say.